# CAS SSO with AD (SPNEGO)

Tags: java, spring-security, active-directory, kerberos, cas

I'm trying to create a deployment with automatic login by using SPNEGO; based on this tutorial: http://jasig.github.io/cas/development/installation/SPNEGO-Authentication.html

I want to use our AD as a Key Distribution Center, so that our domain users are automatically logged in to our application via CAS.

We have a user in our domain, it has an SPN set

A keytab file has been generated for this user, and I have set it in the login.conf file

Here is the relevant section of cas config:

```
<bean id="jcifsConfig" class="org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.authentication.handler.support.JCIFSConfig">
    <property name="jcifsServicePrincipal" value="***SPN***" />
    <property name="kerberosDebug" value="true" />
    <property name="kerberosRealm" value="***REALM/DOMAIN***" />
    <property name="kerberosKdc" value="***Active Directory IP***" />
    <property name="loginConf" value="***Path to login.conf***" />
</bean>
```

Login conf is

```
jcifs.spnego.initiate {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required storeKey=true useKeyTab=true keyTab="***Path tp keytab***";
};
jcifs.spnego.accept {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required storeKey=true useKeyTab=true keyTab="***Path tp keytab***";
};
```

The problem is that all I get is an NTLMSSP token from the client browser. So I can see that some kind of negotiation has been started, but the authentication always fails.

The tutorial/howto references a Kerberos configuration in the "Test SPN account" section. This is something I do not understand. Should I install a Kerberos server on the machine which hosts CAS (it is not something I would prefer)? It does not seem logical to me as I want AD to provide the Kerberos tickets?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Mark.

Edit:

This is the question that really bothers me: **The tutorial/howto references a Kerberos configuration in the "Test SPN account" section. This is something I do not understand. Should I install a Kerberos server on the machine which hosts CAS (it is not something I would prefer)? It does not seem logical to me as I want AD to provide the Kerberos tickets?**

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the browser to do SPNEGO with your CAS site.

Doing this can be anywhere from easy ( Safari on OS/X does it out of the box) to very difficult ( Getting Explorer to trust a website out of your domain. ).

[Old Explorer Version Example](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Negotiation_User_Guide/chap-Web_Browsers.html)

If you are getting NTLM like packets, that means the browser does not recognize your site as one of the sites that it can use kerberos credentials to access.